# google analytics ios sdk V2.0 short session durations

Tags: ios, ipad, google-analytics

The app I'm working on is used on an iPad in a retail display. The device has auto-lock turned off, and the app will show a video loop as a type of screensaver after a minute of inactivity. We are using the GA iOS SDK 2.0 beta to track sessions, with a session timeout of 60 seconds. The app starts a session on startup, and also when the screensaver is dismissed by a touch. This is all working fine except for the multiple 0-10 second long sessions we get, with average duration of 0:00. We can start the app, go through a couple of 60 sec. sessions, then get those sessions reported along with 2-3 of the 0-10 sec. sessions. From what I can see the app only starts sessions when it is supposed to, so I'm wondering if this is related to how Google calculates a session. I haven't seen anything in the documentation that explains this and I'm stumped.

Comment: Session duration measurement works well in my application. Maybe you have made something wrong in your implementation. Otherwise you will have to report it to Google. 2.0 is Beta software and so it may contain issues.

Comment: I just tested the app with automatic session counting and it seems to be completely unreliable. I can run the app, then check the session duration and actually have fewer sessions in one category than I had before and more sessions in a category that shouldn't increase. Reporting it to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this answer from my friend

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144430&topic=1011345&ctx=topic

In my app I only have one view controller that uses [tracker trackView:@"my screen name"] and I have this stuck this in the AppDelegate.m for now as I hadn't got around to tracking views/screens yet.  According to the linked material, the way GA calculates session duration is based on time between views.  Since I only have one view defined (and not properly within the viewController), this may be the reason I'm getting so many 0-10sec sessions.  Going to explore.

Answer (score 0):

It might possible you are initiating a new session before tracking a event/pageview. Please Ensure that you are not starting new session everytime. 
Refer this link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions